# Appery.io navigation by passing variable parameter

Tags: appery.io

I'm listing few user details id,name,place,phno using list control form my DB.
My model(userModel) has these 4 items and the array(userList) has some user elements.
Now i use 
"ng-repeat  user in userList"  to populate the data in list.

On click i want to navigate to an update page containing some input fields where i can update that specific users details. For this i need the id. So i'm passing it to the next page.

I've used a scope function updatePage for navigation.
"ng-click updatePage(user.id)"

Inside updatePage function with argument userId:
Apperyio.navigateTo("UpdatePage", {id : userId});

In next page i've taken value as:
var $routeParams = Apperyio.get( "$routeParams" );
var id = $routeParams.id;

I know passing static value as parameters is easy but...
The problem is i'm always getting the same 'id' no matter which row i clicked.
I think the problem is in the function argument passing when clicked.
Please help. I'm a beginner. 
Is there any other way to implement such a scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can share data and functions between pages in Appery Ionic projects using Angular factories.
Click **Create New > JavaScript** with `Name = UserManager` and `Type = Angular factory`.
Set factory code to

```
    define( ['require'], function( require ){
        function func( Apperyio ){
            var manager = {
                userId: null
            };
            return manager;
        }

        return [{
            /* name for angular resource */
            name: 'userManager',
            /* type of angular resource */
            type: 'factory',
            /* angular dependency injection array */
            deps: [ 'Apperyio', func ]
        }];
    });
```

Then on the 1st page you can set variable before navigating to 2nd page:

```
    Apperyio.get('userManager').userId = user._id;
    Apperyio.navigateTo("UpdatePage");
```

and on the 2nd page you can retrieve it:

```
    var userId = Apperyio.get('userManager').userId;
```